# Nginx returning server error 500 after rest-auth login or registration

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-rest-auth

I am trying to set up authentication on my django app using rest-auth. It works perfectly on the development server, then I pushed to production and started getting server error 500 after every successful login or registration.

This is my urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('api/', include('backend.urls')),
]
```

This is my nginx conf:

```
location /{
include proxy_params;
proxy_pass http://unix:/myapp/path/gunicorn.sock;
}
```

Every route opens correctly even /rest-auth/login, but once I submit the login form or registration form I get the server error but it never happens on development server.

I have tried to make changes in the nginx conf but it didn't work. Every other route works, can this problem be with nginx or rest-auth(it works on development)?

Comment: Check the gunicorn logs fir the error message.

Comment: @KlausD. the gunicorn error file is empty. It didn't log any error